# обновил андроид студио до 2.3 ошибка adb

Tags: android, adb

IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

Answer (score 0):

Как написано здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778344/illegalargumentexception-unable-to-locate-adb-in-android-studio-v2-3

Вам нужно перейти Tools >> Android >> SDK-Manager >> SDK-Tools и снять галочку рядом с `Android SDK Platform-Tools`и нажать `Apply` чтобы удалить пакет.

После этого перезапустите студию и снова поставьте галочку, чтобы установить этот пакет